# {% if {{ row['rating']}} == 5 %} jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'

Tags: html

When I run my code I get the error stated above. It is the first time I try to use an if statement inside html so I don't really know how to fix it.

```
<td id="stars">
              <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span><span class="fa fa-star checked"></span><span class="fa fa-star checked"></span><span class="fa fa-star checked"></span><span class="fa fa-star checked"></span></td>
            {% elsif {{ row['rating']}} == 4 %}
            <td id="stars">
              <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span><span class="fa fa-star checked"></span><span class="fa fa-star checked"></span><span class="fa fa-star checked"></span></td>
            {% elsif {{ row['rating']}} == 3 %}
            <td id="stars">
              <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span><span class="fa fa-star checked"></span><span class="fa fa-star checked"></span></td>
            {% elsif {{ row['rating']}} == 2 %}
            <td id="stars">
              <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span><span class="fa fa-star checked"></span></td>
            {% elsif {{ row['rating']}} == 1 %}
            <td id="stars">
              <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span></td>
            {% endif %> }
          </tr>
```

Comment: That isn't plain HTML but some templating engine. Can you please identify what technology this question is about?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the double curly braces in the if statements, for example:

```
{% if row['rating'] == 4 %}
```